# Calling a feign service consecutively in a for loop causes some calls to get "Connect timed out executing POST http:..." error

Tags: java, microservices, feign, connect-timeout

In a for loop when we call a specific feign service 115 times, 18 of the calls end up with an error saying "Connect timed out executing POST http:...". what could be the reason for this? Every time this process works some of the calls get this error while other among around 100 calls are successful. I know making so many feign calls in such a for loop is not a nice design choice but I wonder the reason behind this error. Why are some of the calls fail while lots of them are successful?